# store memory address in a char* and & in gdb

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I am trying to create a chain of pointer addresses, with the first pointing to address of the next, and so on.

For example, `char *a` 's address is `0x1`, `char *b` address is `0x2`, `char *x` address is `0x3`. I want to link `a`->`b`->`c`, so that my hope is to store value `0x2` into `0x1` memory address, value `0x3` into `0x2` memory address.

I have following codes:

```
#define PUT(p, val) (*(unsigned long *)(p) = (val))
#define SET_NEXT_PTR(p, ptr) (*(char**)(p) = (char*)((unsigned long)(ptr)))
void chain(char* bp){
    char *first = mem_sbrk(size);
    char *second =mem_sbrk(size);
    PUT(first, (unsigned long)bp);
    PUT(bp, *second);
}
```

When I run gdb, and exam those memory address. After call `mem_sbrk` for first and second.

```
(gdb) x /x first
0x7ffff661c020: 0x00000000

(gdb) x /x bp 
0x7ffff661b020: 0x00000000
(gdb) x/x second 
0x7ffff661d020: 0x00000000
```

After call `PUT` macro:

```
(gdb) x/x second 
0x7ffff661d020: 0x00000000      0x00000000
(gdb) x /2x first
0x7ffff661c020: 0xf661b020      0x00007fff   
(gdb) p first 
0x7ffff661c020 " \260a\366\377\177"  
(gdb) x /2x bp
0x7ffff661b020: 0xf661d020      0x00007fff
```

It seems working. But I wonder how can I convert those memory address to a pointer. Since entire memory address stores into `0x7ffff661d020` and `0x7ffff661d024`. When I use `p` first, it returns a meaningless string.

Second question, in gdb when I call

```
(gdb) p &bp
(char **) 0x7fffffffe3e8
```

I wonder what is `0x7fffffffe3e8`? I thought `&` is for getting memory address,I expect gdb shows

```
(void*) 0x7ffff661b020
```

Third question what is difference between

```
#define PUT(p, val) (*(unsigned long *)(p) = (val))
#define SET_NEXT_PTR(p, ptr) (*(char**)(p) = (char*)((unsigned long)(ptr)))
```

Comment: What is the value of *size*?

Comment: size is 1024, value of size does not matter